# send user inputs from a form directly to mail in Zip format

Tags: php, file, email, input, zip

I'm designing a form. There will be approximate 100 user input fields ( all of them are not mandatory off course  ). All I need is that I have to sent the user inputs to mail in zip format and file name should be accordingly one of its input. Can someone please help me with idea how to achieve this?

Thank You all.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this

```
 $zip = new ZipArchive;
 $filePath = $fullPath.$_POST['name_input'].'.zip';
 $file = $zip->open($fullPath.$_POST['name_input'].'.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE);
 $txtInputs = '';
 foreach($_POST['inputs'] as $key => $input){
     $txtInputs.=  $key.': '.$input."";
 }
$zip->addFromString('name_file.txt',  $txtInputs);
$zip->close();



  //send email -> add attach $filePath
```